# How to search through pubmed using R, as is possible with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, r

I just came by the Ruby function

```
ncbi.esearch_count
```

Used in a recent post [here (regarding the use of the word noval in publications)](http://www.r-bloggers.com/findings-increasingly-novel-scientists-say%E2%80%A6/), used to search in [pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed).

And I wonder how can it be done using R (via maybe Rcurl, or other library(XML) functions)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ruby function is part of the [BioRuby](http://bioruby.org/) library, which provides a wrapper around the [NCBI EUtils](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/).  There was some [brief discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2007-January/015756.html) at the R Bioconductor mailing list regarding a wrapper for R, but I don't think that it went anywhere.

It is possible to use EUtils using RCurl and XML as you suggest.  You construct the correct query URL, fetch the results using RCurl and parse using XML.  I'd recommend reading the documentation in the second link for details about URLs; it is not very difficult.  However, I don't think that there is a pure EUtils equivalent of BioRuby's very useful esearch_count().

EDIT: may be wrong on that last point, there is [EGQuery](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/corehtml/query/static/egquery_help.html).

Comment: Hello Neilfws, Thank you for replying.  I see the link in the link you gave is broken.  I couldn't find the package refered to there - do you happen to know where to find it?

Comment: I saw that too - which is why I suspect it was not developed further. There seems to be some code here - http://sites.google.com/site/gregorgorjanc/software - but it is dated 2006 and described as "proof of concept".

Comment: How interesting.  It appears Gregor already has a blog on R-bloggers.com.  I just e-mailed him, and I hope he might be willing/able to help.

Comment: I got a response - it seems that this package can work (I will simply need to rebuild it from binaries).  Thank you for the help neilfws.

Answer (score 3):

There is an article by Duncan Temple Lang, arguably the Dean of R Web Services, that was apparently destined for the Journal of Statistical Software illustrating accessing PubMed with RCurl. I can only find it at the Omegahat website:

["R as a Web Client – the RCurl package"](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.omegahat.org%2FRCurl%2FRCurlJSS.pdf&ei=FMDOTMHNJ4P58AbV6oTBAw&usg=AFQjCNFsknLP5h7Hv9I71NnpR3P1iVkehA)

Comment: Wonderful link - It only illustrates how to log in using a cookie, but still this is a gem.  Thank you DWin!